# Sugar ORM Android With multiple databases

Tags: android, database, orm, multiple-databases, sugarorm

I am trying to create an application for multiple users with multiple database. Each time a user login ,App will select the particular user's database and fetch the values from it. Is it possible to implement it with Sugar ORM because in Sugar ORM , we can specify only One db in manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="Example.db" />
```

Is there any possible to way to close the existing DB and select another DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked the same question on the Sugar [GitHub Library](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/653).

There are multiple issues on the GitHub Repo that mention the multiple database idea ([example](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/596)). All these issues are still open and do not show a solution.

You can also not find anything about it at the wiki.

So you can conclude it is **not** possible in SugarORM.

Comment: yeah,it seems it's impossible to use multiple database with sugar.