# How to send sugar ORM database to server as a file?

Tags: android, sugarorm

I want to send my sugar orm database to server, I have read [send a file in Android from a mobile device to server using http](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126746/9881118) and [Location of sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device) but I don't know how to get the path of my sugar orm db and send it as file, I don't want to send it as json ,just send it as a  file. Can anyone tell me how to send my orm database to server and what is the default path of sugar orm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sugar ORM` is based on `sqlite`, so the path of sugar database is the same as `sqllite`.
For getting database path you can use:

```
Context context = this; // for Activity, or Service.
String dbname = "mydb.db";
Path dbpath = context.getDatabasePath(dbname);
```

The path would be something like:

```
/data/data/com.me.myapp/databases/mydb.db
```

Comment: is there a way to send just one of the tables?not the whole db

Comment: No, except you store it in separate database. If you find answer useful accept and up-vote it.

Comment: but according to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791933/9881118) it seems impossible to make more than one db with sugar,tnx for yr answer